# roslaunch phantom_ns.launch is giving error

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,
I am new to ROS and ubuntu, I am using ROS package which I cloned from github
When I run roslaunch phantom_ns.launch

I get the following error,

[phantom_ns.launch] requires the 'DefaultPHANToM' arg to be set.

Please guide me how can I resolve this error.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95861/roslaunch-phantom_ns.launch-is-giving-error/) by [Nabeel9172](https://answers.ros.org/users/8266/nabeel9172/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you publish here the content of the phantom_ns.launch file?

---

Originally posted by [maska](https://answers.ros.org/users/7951/maska/) with karma: 61 on 2013-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nabeel9172](https://answers.ros.org/users/8266/nabeel9172/) on 2013-10-30**:
Thank you for your reply.. I resolved the issue. In launch file there are two arg defined and I was not setting their values in roslaunch command..I used below command which worked for me..
roslaunch phantom_ns.launch PHANToM:=true publish_rate:=5

**Comment by [maska](https://answers.ros.org/users/7951/maska/) on 2013-10-30**:
You could add a default value into you launch file. It should look something like


instead adding them each time in console